Having a problem with the order Kotlin Compose paint the Scaffold Body and Content. Draws Content first then Body, I need Body then Content
I have my Main Screen on a Scaffold structure as below code, but instead of drawing the Scaffold body first and then the Content it does it the other way around. What can I do?
MyAppTheme {

val componentHeightT = remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
val componentHeightB = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        
val imeState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            Scaffold(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .navigationBarsPadding()
                    .systemBarsPadding(),
                topBar = {
                        TopNavigation(navController, myViewModel, componentHeightT)
                },
                bottomBar = {
                        if (!imeState.value) BottomNavigation(navController, myViewModel,componentHeightB)
                },
            ) {

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(
                            top = componentHeightT.value,
                            bottom = componentHeightB.value.toDp.dp
                        ),

                        /*.navigationBarsPadding()
                        .systemBarsPadding(),*/
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Log.d("test", "Entered Theme")
                    
                    //A LOT OF CODE
               }
           }
 }

The topBar and bottomBar are shown some time(a second or less) after the Surface.  I need them first as inside the Surface I use [componentHeightT, componentHeightB] to modify the position of it's objects and other Composables shift position after the topBar is shown.
